# Laravel - Accessing stored images in storage/app/public

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to show an image on a View, with the filename stored in a database, using laravel Storage function.

Using `<img src="{{ Storage::url($surgery->image) }}" alt="">` where `$surgery->image` contains the filename generates this HTML:

```
<img src="/storage/XY6TswNTTxTMtDWsxz9O3OUhPmfZZBaZPRLUPKAy.jpeg" alt="">
```

I already created a symlink to storage/app/public (used the command `php artisan storage:link`). 
A quick `ls` public/storage shows me the image is there.

```
ls public/storage
XY6TswNTTxTMtDWsxz9O3OUhPmfZZBaZPRLUPKAy.jpeg
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use the complete url like http://example.com/storage/XY6TswNTTxTMtDWsxz9O3OUhPmfZZBaZPRLUPKAy.jpeg?

Comment: Does storage have correct permissions to access storage folder?

Comment: @TosinJohn The complete url gives me "Object not found" Apache error.
Also I just did a chmod -R 777 on the project folder for testing, same faulty behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Despite images are linked to the correct place, double-check its permissions.
(Set to `777` just for testing)

Comment: I did, no changes, still fails to retrieve the image

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem, what I later did was that I saved only the file name in the database, i.e `XY6TswNTTxTMtDWsxz9O3OUhPmfZZBaZPRLUPKAy.jpeg` only will be in the data base or wherever you're saving the data, hence `$surgery->image` should return `XY6TswNTTxTMtDWsxz9O3OUhPmfZZBaZPRLUPKAy.jpeg`.
You may now load the image in your database using this code:

```
<img src='{{ asset("storage/$surgery->image")}}' alt="">
```

Please take note of how I used the double quotes and single quote for the `src` attribute of the `img` tag.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: `<img src="{{ asset("storage/...") }}"/>` is actually ok, despite using `"` inside `"`

Comment: @TimLewis Yes it may not affect your code, but I use notpad++ and it affects my codes color

Comment: Ah, that's a good point; it would mess up syntax highlighting, even though, ironically, it's syntactically-valid.

Comment: Tried using your method, still no success. It generates this html:
`<img src="http://localhost/storage/public/NGiNxEfdml5bD64TlQWG2UeknlcTYvhnfQuBHGz1.jpeg" alt="">` and still no resource found. (I know the filename is different, I used a different image)

Comment: Did you create a local virtual host for your laravel project? This should definitely work if you had done so.